# Complex conditions in CanCanCan can method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

If I have user,client and request models as follows:

```html
#user.rb


#client.rb
has_one :user
has_many :requests

#request.rb
belongs_to :client
```

I use user model for CanCanCan authentication.
Inside ability class i want to specify ability for client. I want to user to allow read,update only for requests that belong to him.
Her is what i try:

```html
def client
  can [:read,:update], [Request], ['client_id = ?', user.client_id] do |client|
      ......something here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
can [:read, :update], Request, :client_id => user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the simplest option:

```
can [:read, :update], Request, :client_id => user.id
```

if you have more complex abilities than this then you can do:

```
can [:read, :update], Request do |request|
  request.client_id == user.id
end
```